# Problem with Queues and Dynamically Allocated Structures in C

Tags: c, queue, dynamic-memory-allocation, freertos

I will start with a brief introduction to what I'm doing.

I am writing a library for a microcontroller device that can be used to control a certain application on PC over UART. The first draft of the application was purely sequential - a set of functions that can be called from the library in order to send certain data to PC. This worked but had potential problems since the execution was sequential and if something went wrong, the whole program would collapse. I decided to incorporate freeRTOS into the library in order to have better control over the execution and there is where the problems ensued. I will try to the best of my abilities to bring the problem closer to you by presenting only the essential code parts.

Let me briefly give you a summed up review of the first version of the library. I will provide only the code that I think is essential.

```c
/* main.c

Contains a task that uses library functions to send commands.

*/

/* prvControlTask

Uses library functions to control PC application over UART.

*/
static void prvControlTask( void *pvParameters )
{
    TickType_t xNextWakeTime;
 
    /* Remove compiler warning about unused parameter. */
    ( void ) pvParameters;
    xNextWakeTime = xTaskGetTickCount();

    /* Using some library functions */
    connect(0x00, "Mike", "Mike-123");   // Connects to the PC app
    play(0x00, "move", "right");         // Control some app aspect
    play(0x00, "move", "right-up");
    play(0x00, "move", "right-down");
    play(0x00, "jump", "left-down");

    for( ;; )
    {     
        /* Place this task in the blocked state until it is time to run again. */
        vTaskDelayUntil( &xNextWakeTime, mainQUEUE_SEND_FREQUENCY_MS );
    }
}
```

Over in the library, there are 3 data structures that the library uses:

```c
/* library

Contains structures and functions for UART-PC control

*/

char uart_bytes[100];  // Used to send bytes to uart

struct CONNECT{        // To help store data for connect function
    uint8_t player_type;

    char* username;
    char* password;
};

struct PLAY{          // To help store data for play function
    uint8_t player_type;

    char* command;
    char* direction;
};
```

The functions themselves are pretty straight-forward. The called function fills the structure and sends it to another function which turns it's data into bytes and fills uart_bytes and sends those bytes over UART.

```c
/* library

Contains structures and functions for UART-PC control

*/

void connect(uint8_t player_type, char* username, char* password){
    struct CONNECT connect_data = {0};
    connect_data.player_type = player_type;
    connect_data.username = username;
    connect_data.password = password;

    send_connect_struct(&connect_data);
}

void send_connect_struct(struct CONNECT * connect_data){
    /*
    Turns data player_type, username, password into byte array and fills uart_bytes and sends to PC over UART.
    */
}

/*

Exactly the same for the play functions.

*/
```

This all works as it should. I am observing the data being sent and it all agrees with what the function was called with. This shows that there are no problems with the functions themselves if the data is properly given.

The problems could arise when there is delay or an error in connect or some play command and if it fails, all others will fail as well since it disconnects on wrong command. Here I thought about using freeRTOS.

The idea is to have a task inside the library that will take data from a queue and call the corresponding command based on that data. When the user calls a function from the main.c, the function will simply create a structure of that command, store it in the queue and finish. Then the queue will have pending commands and the task can simply take one by one from those commands and execute the appropriate send function.

Here is the structure that will be stored in a queue.

```c
struct COMMAND{            // Used to hold commands into a queue for the task to execute
    uint8_t command_type;

    struct CONNECT * connect_data;
    struct PLAY * play_data;
}
```

Here is the queue that holds the commands.

```c
QueueHandle_t xCommandQueue;  // global variable

void start_tasks(void){
    xCommandQueue = xQueueCreate(32, sizeof(struct COMMAND*));

    /* Creating a task */
    xTaskCreate( prvLIBTask, "LibTask", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE, NULL, TASK_PRIORITY, &xTaskHandle );
}
```

And here is the task that will run.

```c
void prvLIBTask( void *pvParameters )  // Task that receives from the queue and sends command
{
    struct COMMAND* rec_command;
 
    /* Remove compiler warning about unused parameter. */
    ( void ) pvParameters;

    for( ;; )
    {     
        /* Wait until something is received from the queue */
        while(!xQueueReceive( xCommandQueue, &rec_command, portMAX_DELAY ));

        if (rec_command->command_type == 0x00)
        {
          send_connect_struct(&(*rec_command->connect_data));
          free(rec_command);
        }
        else if (rec_command->command_type == 0x01)
        {
          send_play_struct(&(*rec_command->play_data));
          free(rec_command);
        }
    }
}
```

The functions that are called from the main (connect and play) look like this.

```c
void connect(uint8_t player_type, char* username, char* password){
    struct CONNECT *connect_data = malloc(sizeof(struct CONNECT));
    connect_data->player_type = player_type;
    connect_data->username = malloc(strlen(username)+1);
    memcpy(connect->data.username, username, strlen(connect_data.username)+1);
    connect_data->password = malloc(strlen(password)+1);
    memcpy(connect_data->password, password, strlen(connect_data.password)+1);

    struct COMMAND* latest_command = malloc(sizeof(struct COMMAND));
    latest_command->command_type = 0x00;
    latest_command->connect_data = &(*connect_data);

    xQueueSend( xCommandQueue, &(latest_command), portMAX_DELAY ); 
}

/*

Almost exactly the same process for play.

Note that in the send_connect_struct and send_play_struct, at the end of the function I am freeing all the char* fields first and then the passed structure.

Example:

free(connect_data->username);
free(connect_data->password);
free(connect_data);

Since the queue will copy the contents of the pointer, the receive end of the queue will see the actual memory location of the allocated data and therefore can free it at the end of the execution.

*/
```

The problem is that the CONNECT command goes fine and I see the right data getting sent but the PLAY commands have problems where sometimes the first PLAY will go but the second one will have messed up data. Sometimes it even gets stuck after CONNECT function as I see that the function doesn't even exit the play(). It definitely is something with the dynamic memory allocation but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

The weirdest thing is that when I do not allocate the structure fields but just say for example (part of the connect()):

```c
    struct CONNECT connect_data = malloc(sizeof(struct CONNECT));
    connect_data->player_type = player_type;
    connect_data->username = username;
```

it does send correct data for connect and play but this cannot be since the pointers of the structures will point to stack memory (that holds username and pass from parameters passed to the function), right?

Do you see a mistake here?

**Edit**:

Here are the functions I'm calling:

```c
connect(0x00, "Mike", "Mike123");
play(0x00, "move", "right");       
play(0x00, "move", "right-up");
play(0x00, "move", "right-down");
```

Here is the queue:

```c
xCommandQueue = xQueueCreate(32, sizeof(struct COMMAND));
```

Here is the receiving task:

```c
void prvLIBTask( void *pvParameters )  // Task that receives from the queue and sends command
{
    struct COMMAND rec_command;

    /* Remove compiler warning about unused parameter. */
    ( void ) pvParameters;

    for( ;; )
    {     
        /* Wait until something is received from the queue */
        while(!xQueueReceive( xCommandQueue, &rec_command, portMAX_DELAY ));

        if (rec_command.command_type == 0x00)
        {
          /* functions to print structure field */
          send_connect_struct(rec_command.connect_data);
        }
        else if (rec_command.command_type == 0x01)
        {
          /* functions to print structure field */
          send_play_struct(rec_command.play_data);
        }
    }
}
```

And here are the functions:

```c
void connect(uint8_t player_type, char* username, char* password){

    struct CONNECT *connect_data = malloc(sizeof(struct CONNECT));
    connect_data->player_type = player_type;
    connect_data->username = malloc(strlen(username)+1);
    memcpy(connect_data->username, username, strlen(username)+1);
    connect_data->password = malloc(strlen(password)+1);
    memcpy(connect_data->password, password, strlen(password)+1);

    struct COMMAND* latest_command = malloc(sizeof(struct COMMAND));
    latest_command->command_type = 0x00;
    latest_command->connect_data = connect_data;

    xQueueSend( xCommandQueue, latest_command, portMAX_DELAY ); 
}

void play(uint8_t player_type, char* command, char* direction){

    struct PLAY *play_data = malloc(sizeof(struct PLAY));
    play_data->player_type = player_type;
    play_data->command = malloc(strlen(command)+1);
    memcpy(play_data.command, command, strlen(command)+1);
    play_data->direction = malloc(strlen(direction)+1);
    memcpy(play_data->direction, direction, strlen(direction)+1);

    struct COMMAND* latest_command = malloc(sizeof(struct COMMAND));
    latest_command->command_type = 0x01;
    latest_command->play_data = play_data;

    xQueueSend( xCommandQueue, latest_command, portMAX_DELAY ); 
}
```

**The Results**:

The result of the print functions right after I receive from the Queue:

```
CONNECT
type = 0x00
username = Mike
password = Mike123
```

and then the code blocks somewhere in the publish function. I don't receive any publish messages.

If I however don't allocate for the char* fields in the publish and instead use:

```c
play_data->player_type = player_type;
play_data->player_type = command;
play_data->player_type = direction;
```

I get the following output:

```
CONNECT
type = 0x00
username = Mike
password = Mike123

PUBLISH
type = 0x00
username = move
password = right

PUBLISH
type = 0x00
username = move
password = right-up

PUBLISH
type = 0x00
username = move
password = 0
```

So the first two publishes are OK but the second one says 0. I don't get this since they are created by the same function.

The send_connect_struc and send_play_struc work fine when given correct data like in the first three cases. Both functions are of this template:

```c
void send_play_struc(struc PLAY* play_data) {
   /* fill uart_bytes */
   free(play_data->command);
   free(play_data->direction);
   free(play_data);
}
```

Comment: it looks like you are sending pointers over the line. if so, that won't work. Those pointers are only valid in the process on the sending side.

Comment: I tried sending the entire struct COMMAND by creating the Queue to be sizeof(struct COMMAND) but still it didn't work. If I send the entire struct, the struct fields will be copied including the pointers to structures CONNECT and PLAY but will they be valid? Also, will the pointers inside those structures be valid? If not, what should I do instead?

Comment: No, those pointers will not be valid on the receiving end. You need to build some serializing meachanism.

Comment: Well since I want to store multiple COMMAND struct in the queue to "wait" for their turn and since the pointers are invalid when created in the function, what is the solution?

Comment: I'd add a function for each struct that you want to serialize. `read_COMMAND`, `write_COMMAND`, `read_CONNECT`, `write_CONNECT`, `read_PLAY` and `write_PLAY` for example. Instead of sending pointers, thost would send a flattened version of the data. When you send strings, you could either send the null terminated strings, but it's often nice to send the length of the string first to make it easy for the receiver to allocate the correct amount of memory. If no string can be more than 255 characters, you'd only need one byte for the length.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood. You should show the `send_connect_struct` function too.

Comment: Right before I call send_connect_struct in the task that receives from the queue I'm checking the contents of the structure I received and there I see that something is wrong with eg. password or username. That is why the sending is failing. Whenever I receive correct data the sending works fine so it's 100% not the function.

Comment: @EdwardBlack Can you check if the changes that I proposed in my answer do fix your problem?

Comment: @LucaPolito I have edited the question with more details and I applied your changes to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `connect()` has some problems:

```c
void connect(uint8_t player_type, char* username, char* password){
    // you must check for NULL
    struct CONNECT *connect_data = malloc(sizeof(struct CONNECT));

    connect_data->player_type = player_type;

    // you must check for NULL
    connect_data->username = malloc(strlen(username)+1);

    // this line is wrong
    //memcpy(connect->data.username, username, strlen(connect_data.username)+1);

    // corrected version
    memcpy(connect_data->username, username, strlen(username) + 1);

    // you must check for NULL
    connect_data->password = malloc(strlen(password)+1);

    // this line is wrong
    //memcpy(connect_data->password, password, strlen(connect_data.password)+1);

    // corrected version
    memcpy(connect_data->password, password, strlen(password) + 1);

    // you must check NULL
    struct COMMAND* latest_command = malloc(sizeof(struct COMMAND));

    latest_command->command_type = 0x00;

    // NOTE: `&(*p)` is equivalent to `p`
    latest_command->connect_data = &(*connect_data);

    // here you must pass `latest_command` as argument, not `&(latest_command)`
    xQueueSend( xCommandQueue, &(latest_command), portMAX_DELAY );
}
```

EDIT: the code in which you create the queue is also not correct: since you are pushing items of type `struct COMMAND`, the code to create the queue should be:

```c
xCommandQueue = xQueueCreate(32, sizeof(struct COMMAND)); // this will hold 32 items of type `struct COMMAND`
```

Also, if this code appears to work:

```c
// NOTE: DON'T DO THIS
connect_data.username = username;
connect_data.password = password;
```

... it's because probably you pass string literals as parameters (so `username` and `password` are string literals), and these are usually allocated in the read-only memory area and they usually have the same lifetime of the program itself (i.e.: string literals do not become invalid after you return from the function, because they're not allocated on the stack, usually). Nevertheless, it's a dangerous and restricting assumption to make.

---

EDIT 2: It appears to be a problem related to `malloc()`. You might consider using `pvPortMalloc()` instead of `malloc()` (and `pvPortFree()` instead of `free()`). As a notable remark, `pvPortMalloc()` is thread-safe, while `malloc()` is not.

Comment: This looks like it's suffering from the same problem as OP:s code has. That is, sending pointers over the wire.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't think to understand what you mean. Here, function `xQueueSend()` won't send pointers over the wire, it will just add an item to the queue, and then the item is retrieved by OP in another function and the OP calls `send_connect_struct()` to send the item over the wire. I just assumed OP's `send_connect_struct()` is not broken and correctly sends the `struct` over the wire. I think their problem may be with the queue (as my corrected version of `connect()` pointed out).

Comment: The memcpy mistake was unintentional and I made it as I was writing the question. The corrected version is the same as the real code. As for the queue, my intention was indeed to send the pointers and not the actual struct as the receiving end of the queue copies into the buffer and copying the pointer (location of the allocated struct) made more sense that copying the entire struct which has pointer types in it as well). Nevertheless, even with the actual struct sent, the pointer fields in the received struct don't give out correct data as in the string literal case.

Comment: @EdwardBlack Have you, in particular, checked that inside the `memcpy()` call you have written `strlen(username) + 1` instead of `strlen(connect_data->username)+1`? Plus, in your real code, have you written `xQueueSend( xCommandQueue, latest_command, portMAX_DELAY );` instead of `xQueueSend( xCommandQueue, &(latest_command), portMAX_DELAY );`?

Comment: @LucaPolito Yes, I have changed everything you stated here. Please see the edit of the question. I have added more details and the results of the execution.

Comment: @EdwardBlack It could be a problem related to `malloc()`. Check if the output of the various calls to `malloc()` ever return `NULL`. You might also consider using [`pvPortMalloc()`](https://www.freertos.org/a00111.html) instead of `malloc()` (and `pvPortFree()` instead of `free()`, but for now I'd suggest to comment out all the memory freeing calls, just to exclude possible *use after free* bugs and such). P.S.: how many heap memory do you have?

Comment: @LucaPolito  It appears it was the use of pvPortMalloc() that did the trick. Malloc() was the problem. Thank you! If you edit the answer to include that I will accept is as a solution.